# VS Code не может корректно отформатировать выделенный фрагмент HTML-кода в PHP-файле

Tags: visual-studio-code

С текущими настройками или полностью сброшенными, Visual Studio Code вместо конкретного фрагмента HTML-кода форматирует ведь код файла *.php. Eсли же файл формата *.html, то форматирование HTML-кода идет правильно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Причем выделенный фрагмент именно PHP-кода он форматирует корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какие плагины у вас стоят и добавьте все конфиги. у меня ваша проблема не проявляется.

Comment: @DiD Не могу приложить скрин, но всего 4 плагина: HTML CSS Support, PHP Intelephense, Russian Language Pack for Visual Studio Code, Smarty. Настройки я полностью сбрасывал и включал какие-то снова, не помогает. Насколько я понимаю, за форматирование тут отвечает PHP Intelephense.

Answer (score 0):

установите расширения prettier и beautify они очень помогут...

Comment: Установил, но не помогает. Да и непонятно, как они могли бы помочь...

Comment: добавьте настройки в settings.json:  "editor.tabSize": 4,
"editor.formatOnPaste": true

Comment: Это всё конечно не помогает, да и опять же - почему это должно помогать, если форматированием документа занимается плагин PHP Intelephense и это прямо указано в настройках. Если я отключаю этот плагин, то вообще отключается форматирование фрагментов в php-файлах.